# Why is getResults giving me "0"

Tags: solidity

I've copied a smart contract from other project and trying to do my own from there, I understand solidity but I'm not good enough yet to make a contract from scratch.

So, in this contract I have 6 plans, with values are the amount of days and the daily % of profit. This daily % of profit increases 0.5% per day in all 6 plans.

First plan in the index (0) has 14 days and 8% base daily profit.

When I use the getResults function it retrieves the updated daily profit and makes the calculation to let the user know how much profit will get if investing X amount of tokens, but somehow when I enter a deposit:10 in plan:0 gives me a profit of 0, if I enter deposit:100, plan:0 I get the correct math, it's driving me crazy.

Here is the smart contract (had to put it into a snippet because it breaks the bb code in stackoverflow page):

```html
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract testing {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint256 constant public INVEST_MIN_AMOUNT = 10 ether;
    uint256[] public REFERRAL_PERCENTS = [60, 40, 20];
    uint256 constant public PROJECT_FEE = 100;
    uint256 constant public PERCENT_STEP = 5;
    uint256 constant public WITHDRAW_FEE = 1000; //In base point
    uint256 constant public PERCENTS_DIVIDER = 1000;
    uint256 constant public TIME_STEP = 1 days;

    uint256 public totalStaked;
    uint256 public totalRefBonus;

    struct Plan {
        uint256 time;
        uint256 percent;
    }

    Plan[] internal plans;

    struct Deposit {
        uint8 plan;
        uint256 percent;
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 profit;
        uint256 start;
        uint256 finish;
    }

    struct User {
        Deposit[] deposits;
        uint256 checkpoint;
        address referrer;
        uint256[3] levels;
        uint256 bonus;
        uint256 totalBonus;
    }

    mapping (address => User) internal users;

    uint256 public startUNIX;
    address payable public commissionWallet;

    event Newbie(address user);
    event NewDeposit(address indexed user, uint8 plan, uint256 percent, uint256 amount, uint256 profit, uint256 start, uint256 finish);
    event Withdrawn(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
    event RefBonus(address indexed referrer, address indexed referral, uint256 indexed level, uint256 amount);
    event FeePayed(address indexed user, uint256 totalAmount);

    constructor(address payable wallet, uint256 startDate) public {
        require(!isContract(wallet));
        require(startDate > 0);
        commissionWallet = wallet;
        startUNIX = startDate;

        plans.push(Plan(14, 80));
        plans.push(Plan(21, 65));
        plans.push(Plan(28, 50));
        plans.push(Plan(14, 80));
        plans.push(Plan(21, 65));
        plans.push(Plan(28, 50));
    }

    function invest(address referrer, uint8 plan) public payable {
        require(msg.value >= INVEST_MIN_AMOUNT);
        require(plan < 6, "Invalid plan");

        uint256 fee = msg.value.mul(PROJECT_FEE).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
        commissionWallet.transfer(fee);
        emit FeePayed(msg.sender, fee);

        User storage user = users[msg.sender];

        if (user.referrer == address(0)) {
            if (users[referrer].deposits.length > 0 && referrer != msg.sender) {
                user.referrer = referrer;
            }

            address upline = user.referrer;
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (upline != address(0)) {
                    users[upline].levels[i] = users[upline].levels[i].add(1);
                    upline = users[upline].referrer;
                } else break;
            }
        }

        if (user.referrer != address(0)) {

            address upline = user.referrer;
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (upline != address(0)) {
                    uint256 amount = msg.value.mul(REFERRAL_PERCENTS[i]).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
                    users[upline].bonus = users[upline].bonus.add(amount);
                    users[upline].totalBonus = users[upline].totalBonus.add(amount);
                    emit RefBonus(upline, msg.sender, i, amount);
                    upline = users[upline].referrer;
                } else break;
            }

        }

        if (user.deposits.length == 0) {
            user.checkpoint = block.timestamp;
            emit Newbie(msg.sender);
        }

        (uint256 percent, uint256 profit, uint256 finish) = getResult(plan, msg.value);
        user.deposits.push(Deposit(plan, percent, msg.value, profit, block.timestamp, finish));

        totalStaked = totalStaked.add(msg.value);
        emit NewDeposit(msg.sender, plan, percent, msg.value, profit, block.timestamp, finish);
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        User storage user = users[msg.sender];

        uint256 totalAmount = getUserDividends(msg.sender);
        uint256 fees = totalAmount.mul(WITHDRAW_FEE).div(10000);
           totalAmount = totalAmount.sub(fees);

        uint256 referralBonus = getUserReferralBonus(msg.sender);
        if (referralBonus > 0) {
            user.bonus = 0;
            totalAmount = totalAmount.add(referralBonus);
        }

        require(totalAmount > 0, "User has no dividends");

        uint256 contractBalance = address(this).balance;
        if (contractBalance < totalAmount) {
            totalAmount = contractBalance;
        }

        user.checkpoint = block.timestamp;
        

        msg.sender.transfer(totalAmount);

        emit Withdrawn(msg.sender, totalAmount);

    }

    function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getPlanInfo(uint8 plan) public view returns(uint256 time, uint256 percent) {
        time = plans[plan].time;
        percent = plans[plan].percent;
    }

    function getPercent(uint8 plan) public view returns (uint256) {
        if (block.timestamp > startUNIX) {
            return plans[plan].percent.add(PERCENT_STEP.mul(block.timestamp.sub(startUNIX)).div(TIME_STEP));
        } else {
            return plans[plan].percent;
        }
    }

    function getResult(uint8 plan, uint256 deposit) public view returns (uint256 percent, uint256 profit, uint256 finish) {
        percent = getPercent(plan);

        if (plan < 3) {
            profit = deposit.mul(percent).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER).mul(plans[plan].time);
        } else if (plan < 6) {
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < plans[plan].time; i++) {
                profit = profit.add((deposit.add(profit)).mul(percent).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER));
            }
        }

        finish = block.timestamp.add(plans[plan].time.mul(TIME_STEP));
    }

    function getUserDividends(address userAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
        User storage user = users[userAddress];

        uint256 totalAmount;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < user.deposits.length; i++) {
            if (user.checkpoint < user.deposits[i].finish) {
                if (user.deposits[i].plan < 3) {
                    uint256 share = user.deposits[i].amount.mul(user.deposits[i].percent).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
                    uint256 from = user.deposits[i].start > user.checkpoint ? user.deposits[i].start : user.checkpoint;
                    uint256 to = user.deposits[i].finish < block.timestamp ? user.deposits[i].finish : block.timestamp;
                    if (from < to) {
                        totalAmount = totalAmount.add(share.mul(to.sub(from)).div(TIME_STEP));
                    }
                } else if (block.timestamp > user.deposits[i].finish) {
                    totalAmount = totalAmount.add(user.deposits[i].profit);
                }
            }
        }

        return totalAmount;
    }

    function getUserCheckpoint(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].checkpoint;
    }

    function getUserReferrer(address userAddress) public view returns(address) {
        return users[userAddress].referrer;
    }

    function getUserDownlineCount(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        return (users[userAddress].levels[0], users[userAddress].levels[1], users[userAddress].levels[2]);
    }

    function getUserReferralBonus(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].bonus;
    }

    function getUserReferralTotalBonus(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].totalBonus;
    }

    function getUserReferralWithdrawn(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].totalBonus.sub(users[userAddress].bonus);
    }

    function getUserAvailable(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return getUserReferralBonus(userAddress).add(getUserDividends(userAddress));
    }

    function getUserAmountOfDeposits(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].deposits.length;
    }

    function getUserTotalDeposits(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256 amount) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < users[userAddress].deposits.length; i++) {
            amount = amount.add(users[userAddress].deposits[i].amount);
        }
    }

    function getUserDepositInfo(address userAddress, uint256 index) public view returns(uint8 plan, uint256 percent, uint256 amount, uint256 profit, uint256 start, uint256 finish) {
        User storage user = users[userAddress];

        plan = user.deposits[index].plan;
        percent = user.deposits[index].percent;
        amount = user.deposits[index].amount;
        profit = user.deposits[index].profit;
        start = user.deposits[index].start;
        finish = user.deposits[index].finish;
    }

    function isContract(address addr) internal view returns (bool) {
        uint size;
        assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
        return size > 0;
    }
}

library SafeMath {

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, "SafeMath: division by zero");
        uint256 c = a / b;

        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue. Since we are only handling integers there are no double type of variables, in the division it was rounding to 0, then when multiplied still being 0.

I've changed the div to be last part of the operation.

Replace this:

```
profit = deposit.mul(percent).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER).mul(plans[plan].time);
```

to this:

```
profit = deposit.mul(percent).mul(plans[plan].time).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
```